# Laravel redirect ALL types of errors to custom view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way to catch all possible errors and redirect all types of errors to 1 page.

My current code in `/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
    $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();

    switch ($statusCode) {
        case '404':
            return response()->view('layouts/404');
    }
}
```

Problem is that **ErrorException (E_NOTICE)** types (which are caused by possible bugs in the code) aren't redirected to the 404 page. These errors end up on the 'Woops something went wrong' page.

I basically am trying to make every type of error end up on my custom error page.

All attempts end up on white pages.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: I am confused. You want to render all possible exceptions as 404s?

Comment: @Mozammil Indeed!

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I am sorry, I had to retract my answer. It's a terribly bad idea to do that. All exceptions (including validation) would be rendered as 404. May I know why you want to do that? I could possibly suggest some alternatives then.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Thanks for your help. In some cases I notice that users get redirected to "Woops, something went wrong" page. I actually just want to customise this page, so I created a 404 blade page in my views. 

The only problem is that the application keeps showing the "Woops something went wrong page" instead of my custom page. 

Hope this helps

Comment: @Mozammil see my clarification above.

Comment: Of course they'll continue seeing the "Woops something went wrong" page, an exception is very different to a 404 HTTP response. Exceptions shouldn't be traeted as 404 responses, you sould catch the Exceptions and show the user what is going on.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Yes, I'm aware. That's why I'm looking for a way to redirect that type of exception to the same view (custom 404 blade) as the regular 404 HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do what you're asking for you should go to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` and there, you need to modify the `render` method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        abort(404);
    }
```

But I insist, this is a terrible idea, you should catch the Exceptions that your app may get and show the error message to the user in a clean way, for example:

```
try{
 //... your fancy code here
}catch(Exception $e){
 // return with the message error $e->getMessage()
}
```

Comment: When I add the `abort(404)`, I get a white page instead of the 404 page. (I have the view /views/errors/404.blade)

Comment: It should be working, though. Then try this:

`$notFoundException = new NotFoundHttpException($exception->getMessage());

 return parent::render($request, $notFoundException);`
instead of `abort()`.

Comment: Both options give me blank pages. I re-checked and my 404 file is not empty. 
(/views/errors/404.blade.php)... What am I not seeing..

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using, @RW24 ?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.6