# Make all error status codes return a single custom view

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-8, http-status-codes

[By default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages), Laravel looks for error views under `resources/views/errors`, returning the corresponding view for the relevant status code, eg. 404 or 403. Instead of creating all these views manually I want to use my own custom view for all error codes, with the actual error code and message shown dynamically in the view using  `getMessage()` and any other helper functions that might be available to me.

This would allow me to do this as normal:

```
abort(<statuscode>, <mymessage>)
```

...but always return just the one view.

Note that what I'm asking is *not* the same as what's being requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54238195/laravel-redirect-all-types-of-errors-to-custom-view), which is to force all errors to 404s no matter their actual status code. I want to keep status codes as they should be, just render them all in the same view.

Comment: I don't know of a way to *render* a single view for that. You can have each of the `{code}.blade.php` views *extend* a base view with the same content, but you'd still need to create a file for each expected Error code. You could write your own `abort()` method that has similar logic to this, but renders a single `.blade.php` file instead of a specific one?

Comment: @TimLewis That's a shame, I was hoping this would be simple and/or common enough to be already done by someone. I don't have the skills or the time to write that method right now, so I'll wait for an answer over the next few days and if there isn't one I'll probably just get round to creating each of those files manually.

Comment: No worries! I took a quick look, and didn't see an obvious way of overriding/replacing that function with custom logic. It's possible someone already has, so definitely keep this question open for a bit and maybe consider applying a bounty if you don't get much traction. Cheers!

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for taking a look anyway, I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [default exception handler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L607), a method called `getHttpExceptionView()` determines the view to return. Simply override it in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class with your desired logic.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

protected function getHttpExceptionView($e)
{
    if ($e->getStatusCode() === 409) {
        return "exceptions.special";
    }
    return "exceptions.default";
}
```

You're returning a standard view path, dot-separated if you are using directories.

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for, works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined by [miken32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70933955/1191147), I added the following to the bottom of the `Handler` class inside the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    //  Default classes
    //  ...

    protected function getHttpExceptionView($e)
    {
        //  409 errors are handled specially
        //  Remove this if block entirely to serve them with the same error page as below
        if ($e->getStatusCode() === 409) {
            return "exceptions.special"; 
        }
        return "errors.custom"; // Return a "custom" file under "resources/views/errors"
    }
}
```

I then added the following to my error view:

```
<h1 class="primary-header">
  @if($exception)
    {{"Error " . $exception->getStatusCode().":"}}
    {{ $exception->getMessage() ? $exception->getMessage() : "page not found" }}
  @else {{ "Generic error: page not found" }}
  @endif
</h1>
```

This now allows me to use the `abort()` function in a controller, for example, to throw any HTTP error code with an optional message:

```
Route::get("/failtest/", function (){
        abort(404, "someone messed up");
});
```